# Trying to get started with YII framework, but I'm stuck

Tags: windows, php, xampp

Okay, So I have Xampp installed, and then I have YII installed on localhost inside a directory called "yii". I am now doing a tutorial to learn YII, but I'm stuck on the [following page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app)

They say:

> Run yiic on the command line as follows:
>
> % YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive

What do they mean "run yiic on the command line"? I tried going to localhost/yii/framework/yiic in my browser, but then I get an

> Access denied error

Comment: The command line is accessed through the terminal/console.

Comment: run that command into cmd (command prompt)

Comment: What os you are in? If windows, then it is ms dos prompt.

Comment: I did that but then I get: "'%' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file." I'm in in Windows XP btw.

Comment: dont use '%', use the path to your yii application, eg: c:\wamp\www\myyiiapp\framework

Comment: Basically, in the command prompt, browse to your yii app framework directory, and once in there execute "yiic webapp {path to your application, eg: c:\wamp\www\myyiiapp}"

Comment: Okay, I used 'C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework webapp WebRoot/testdrive"  But I get the same error... I also tried only "C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework" but still getting the same error...

Comment: @ekismo  I just did that, I went to the command prompt and typed in: C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework  but I get the same error

Comment: I also cmd'd "yiic webapp C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework"  still no luck

Comment: Are you able to browse to that directory in command prompt (C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework )? Are you certain that folder exists (browse to it in explorer)?

Comment: Yes, the directory is definitely right... but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right though. In windows xp, I go to "run", and then I type in "cmd", and then I paste "C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework" into the black screen... Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You should be able to type "dir" to view the contents of that directory

Comment: @eskimo and Debrah - that's not correct, as typing a path (except for the root of a drive) in a Windows command prompt will result in an error.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you're having trouble navigating the command prompt.  Here are some detailed steps after you've launched the command prompt via cmd:

First, you'll need to change directory to the webroot.  The command for that will be:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework
```

cd stands for change directory, and you're basically doing the same thing you would be doing in Explorer by clicking on My Computer, then C:, then xampp, then htdocs, etc.  In fact, you could see a similar process if you ran the follow series of commands, and this is often necessary since you need to list directory contents as you go:

```
cd c:\
cd xampp
cd htdocs
cd yii
cd framework
```

Your prompt should then look something like:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework>
```

From there, you'll want to run the command:

```
yiic webapp c:\xampp\htdocs\[path_to_where_you_want_the_app]\testdrive
```

You could also use a relative path instead of the absolute path I provided.

In general, it sounds as if you'll need to brush up a bit on your command line skills, or you'll be encountering issues like this frequently.

Comment: Also, consider a couple of quick-read primers on getting used to the command line. Here's one for Windows: http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7customization/windows-command-promptbeginners-guide/

And here's one for Linux: http://lifehacker.com/5633909/who-needs-a-mouse-learn-to-use-the-command-line-for-almost-anything

Answer (score 0):

`yiic` is a command line tool that provides a way to automate some tasks (e.g building skeleton app for you). In **windows** you get to use it using the command prompt (cmd) & in Unix systems by the terminal.

OK, how about you go to the path where you have Yii installed, you should find a `framework` directory there, well this is the actual yii framework source.
inside that folder you will find two files called yiic but each with different extension, they both do the same job but the one called `yiic.bat` works for Windows OS & the other for Unix/Linux systems.

So now you know **What is it** but **How to get it work**:

Well, it's pretty easy: **First** You [open up](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chdos.htm) the `cmd` & from there you actually have three ways to do it:

1. Navigate to the `framework` folder (using `cd`) then type`yiic` ,
2. Or, like the syntax in your Q, you write the hole path to the `framework` directory followed by `yic`
3. Or (the neater & most convenient way) you [add the path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) of your `framework` folder to Windows environment variables, this way you get to call `yiic` from the `cmd` wherever your location is

**Update:**

in the command: `YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive`
YiiRoot is just an alias, the writer used it because each reader will probably have put the yii source in a diffirent location on his pc so he meant everyone should put their path to yii folder followed by /framework/yiic to run the `yiic` command tool

`webapp` is one of `yiic` command line tool commands to generate an app called **testdrive** under a directory called **WebRoot** (which is another alias and should be replaced by path to Web Server Root e.g htdocs for apache). You can build yii apps without using `yiic` webapp command but it will make things easier and highly recommended for beginners.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed post... but in this tutorial I need to follow (where I'm stuck right now), right after that step it says the following: "This will create a skeleton Yii application under the directory WebRoot/testdrive. The application has a directory structure that is needed by most Yii applications."  Will this actually do that because I don't just need the folder opened though... I don't understand, why did they write the command line as: "% YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive" in the tutorial?

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover your comment points. Try to run the command and see what it does, that will answer most of you questions.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I am using Xamp localhost server. My framework folder is located at: C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework (and I'm very sure this is right) and my webroot is: C:\xampp\htdocs\ - So now what I do is, I click on start (in winXP), then run, then I type in "cmd" which then gives me a black screen. There I paste: "C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\yiic webapp C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrive"  -  but then I get this error: "php.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file".  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Check & follow the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223501/zend-tool-cannot-find-php-exe